# Moving a borderless window in windows seven

Tags: windows, mousemove, borderless

I´ve started working with a new company so I had to switch from Ubuntu to Windows Seven.
On Ubuntu all the GUIs, panels, whatever is visible on the monitor, is movable via key ALT+Mouse. That´s great because if you have a borderless window, you can still move it where you want.

Is there a way to do this on windows ?

Comment: do you want something like ALT+SPACEBAR then M?
(http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=56)

Comment: Is there a reason why it doesn't work on windows 8 ? press alt + spacebar + m, the arrows mouse pointer appears but it does nothing. I don't care because I use AltDrag but I'm curious (no, disabling AltDrag does not fix the problem).

Comment: yeah, that is weird. No idea. Seems like the move option just doesn't work. Somebody should notify ms